# Books on analytic functions on Banach spaces over a non-Archimedean field

Tags: p-adic-analysis, fa.functional-analysis, reference-request, textbook-recommendation

I'm looking for good textbooks on analytic functions on Banach spaces over a non-Archimedean field.
If you know one(s), please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

One beautiful book is Peter Schneider's *Nonarchimedean Functional Analysis*, appeared in the Springer Monographs in Mathematics in 2006. A more analytic one (with less emphasis on Functional Analysis and more on Calculus) in Alain Robert's *A course in $p$-adic Analysis*, GTM 198. But I still think the bible is S. Bosch, U. Güntzer and R. Remmert's *Non-Archimedean Analysis*, appeared in the Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, 261.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the question is about "analytic functions on Banach spaces". This subject from infinite-dimensional analysis seems never studied in the non-Archimedean setting. Already the p-adic analogs of analytic functions behave quite differently from their classical counterparts. 
General monographs on non-Archimedean analysis contain only minimal information on p-adic analytic functions. There are good introductions in the books by Robert and Koblitz. However there are some books devoted specifically to this subject:

Hu, Pei-Chu; Yang, Chung-Chun.
Meromorphic functions over non-Archimedean fields. Dordrecht: Kluwer Academic Publishers. 2000;

A. Escassut, Analytic elements in $p$-adic analysis. Singapore: World Scientific, 1995.

Comment: There is a Bourbaki's volume of the resume of the theory of (possibly infinite dimensional) differential and analytic manifolds over Archimedean(i.e. real and complex) and non-Archimedean fields.
It contains definitions and results but no proofs on the title subject.

Answer (score 2):

Although they are a little older and Anatoly's remark on general monographs might apply here, maybe A. C. M. van Rooij: *Non-archimedean functional analysis* and W. H. Schikhof: *Ultrametric Calculus* still contain helpful information.